# onItemSelectedListener doesn't work

Tags: java, android, sqlite, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I have a `Spinner` on my `Activity` and when I click on an item nothing happens.

The purpose of this `Activity` is to search for a phone contact. It can search by name or by phone number in a `SQLite` database. As you can imagine, if I search by name, the select can find two contacts with the same name, if it happen I want to put the option on the spinner to select what contact i want to see. once I selected the cootact, it is suppose to set the information on the `EditText` fields but it doesnt happen.

Here the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buscar);
    Conexion=new BaseDeDatos(this, "BDCONTACTOS", null, 1);
    alerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    if(Conexion==null){

        alerta.setMessage("LA conexion NO se ha hecho");
        alerta.show();  
        return;
    }
    BD = Conexion.getWritableDatabase();


    nombreTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    telefonoTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    direccionTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    buscarBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    limpiarBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    miSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);


     adp = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,arrayList1);
    miSpinner.setAdapter(adp);
    miSpinner.setDropDownVerticalOffset(50);
    miSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    buscarBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    limpiarBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
{


    int index = miSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    nombreTxt.setText(registros[index][0]);
    telefonoTxt.setText(registros[index][1]);
    direccionTxt.setText(registros[index][2]);

}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v==buscarBtn){
        BD = Conexion.getWritableDatabase();
        if(BD==null){
           alerta.setTitle("Mensaje");
           alerta.setMessage("La base de datos no está abierta");
           alerta.show();   
           return;
        }
        nombre= nombreTxt.getText().toString();
        telefono=telefonoTxt.getText().toString();
        direccion=direccionTxt.getText().toString();

        if(nombre.equals("")&&telefono.equals("")){
            alerta.setTitle("Mensaje");
            alerta.setMessage("Se necesita nombre ó teléfono para buscar");
            alerta.show();  
            return;
        }
        Cursor c;
        if(nombre.equals("")&&!telefono.equals("")){
            String telefono=telefonoTxt.getText().toString();
             c = BD.rawQuery("SELECT Nombre,Telefono,Direccion FROM MisContactos WHERE Telefono='"+telefono+"'", null);

        }
        if(telefono.equals("")&&!nombre.equals("")){
            String nombre=nombreTxt.getText().toString();
            c = BD.rawQuery("SELECT Nombre,Telefono,Direccion FROM MisContactos WHERE Nombre='"+nombre+"'", null);
        }else{
            String telefono=telefonoTxt.getText().toString();
            String nombre=nombreTxt.getText().toString();
            c = BD.rawQuery("SELECT Nombre,Telefono,Direccion FROM MisContactos WHERE Nombre='"+nombre+"' and Telefono='"+telefono+"'", null);
        }
         int count=c.getCount();
         alerta.setMessage("Registros encontrados ="+count);
         alerta.show(); 
           if(count==0)
              return;
           registros=new String[count][3];
           if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                 //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
               int i=0;
                 do {
                    // nombreTxt.setText(c.getString(0)); 
                     registros[i][0]=c.getString(0);
                     //telefonoTxt.setText(c.getString(1)); 
                     registros[i][4]=c.getString(1);
                     //direccionTxt.setText(c.getString(2));    
                     registros[i][5]=c.getString(2);
                    i++;
                 } while(c.moveToNext());
            }

              if(miSpinner.getAdapter().getCount()>0){

                  arrayList1=new ArrayList<String>();
                  adp = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,arrayList1);
                  miSpinner.setAdapter(adp);

              }

              for(int j=0;j<count;j++)
                  arrayList1.add("Ver contacto "+(j+1));



              return;   
          }


    if(v==limpiarBtn){
        limpiar();
        return;
    }
}
public void limpiar(){
    nombreTxt.setText("");
    telefonoTxt.setText("");
    direccionTxt.setText("");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.buscar, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Some screenshots:

the activity at first sight:

[image: the activity at first sight:]

once I search by name, it found two rows:

[image: once I search by name, it found two rows:]

it is suppose to set name, phone number and address (nombre, teléfono, dirección) if I click an option from the spinner (But It doesn't)

[image: it is suppose to set name, phone number and address (nombre, teléfono, dirección) if I click an option from the spinner (But It doesn't)]

This is the first time I ask something in this website. Thank you for your support.

Comment: in Onclick() check for v.getID() == R.id. button1

Comment: I already made that adjustment but I think that is not the problem. Buttons work correctly, the problem is when I click on a Spinner's item nothing happens :c it is suppose to set the info on the EditText field.